# Install Android GUI and Service apk's at once

Tags: android, android-service, android-install-apk

I have an application divided in 2 parts, a service apk and a GUI apk.
This service will provide "methods" called from broadcasts throwed in background from this GUI apk and others.

Since service and GUI apk's are parts of the same application, I want to install both apk's from a single installation process, i.e. a single click on "Install" button at Google Play.

How can I do that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The Android install process can only install one app from an apk.

Furthermore, you can try to include the apk for the second app in the first one and have it installed, but this will not be a silent install and the user will have to approve it the first time he/she runs your app.

Your best bet would be to combine both projects into a single app. You will need to refactor a decent amount, and change the package names of at least one entire app, but it will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But it may not be an option. The main requirement is that other applications have to use services from the app silenty

Comment: Then you will have to install them separately.